# Facebook action

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-actionscript-api

I've an action "check in at" & an object associated with it "venue".
The action is published as:

iThink checked in at `McDonald` on `myapp`

Now I want to modify the story. I want it to appear as:

iThink checked in at `McDonald`  and the place is buzzing on `myapp`

How to do the later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to look into [flexible sentences](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/flexible_sentences/) for open graph actions.  You can customize how your sentences look on the Open Graph section of your app's dashboard.